# Wordpress rewrite rule with custom taxonomy and custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have custom post_type called 'video' and custom taxonomy "channels"

I want to rewrite my video details page like this:

```
http://example.com/funny/<postname>
```

here "funny" is channels term.

I tried some code like:

```
add_permastruct( 'video', '%channels%/%video%' );
```

It's working fine but when I'm trying to open post details page whose permalink structure is:

```
http://example.com/<parent_category>/<postname>
```

it's not working.  All post single page show 404.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you should achive your result customizing the **rewrite** property on your post type definition:

Custom Post type id -> **video**

**video** Custom taxonomy id -> **ct_video**

Custom Post type id -> **channels**

**channels** custom taxonomy id -> **ct_channels**

if you want to customize your custom post type or cutom taxonomy archive or page:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '[custom url]')
```

to personalize the url of your posts I advise you to download **Custom Post Type Permalinks** : https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/
and you can use it like this:

[image]

defining the custom post type post url using the structure tags